# SharpSnmpLib SNMP read exception using library SharpSnmpLib

Tags: exception, wireshark, packet, sharp-snmp

I get exception when doing snmp get.

Here is the Wireshark dump of the packet that gives the exception:

[image: wireshark dump of the packet that gives the exception]

> Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.SnmpException: data construction exception --->
>   System.ArgumentException: Truncation error for 32-bit integer coding.
>   Parameter name: length

Comment: can you please add some more context information

Comment: I found the problem I was sending too big requestID or negative requestID which are not supported by some devices!

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem I was sending too big requestID or negative requestID which are not supported by some devices!
Use this option to disable negative request ID
Messenger.UseFullRange = false;